# Google Tag Manager - DataLayer

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We are struggling with how to achieve the following:

Imagine you have 3 images on a web page distributed vertically on a page.
If we create a Tag for Visibility based on a class (say .viewed) that all images share, then every time the user scrolls to each image, the Tag fires.

At this point we would like to associate some data to each images that triggered the Tag.

```
dataLayer.push({
               'variableName': { 'id': $('#promos .viewed').attr('id'), 'group': 'HomeBottom' }
      });
```

This code will push the variable so that it will be available to the tag manager. But how can we get the id and group for each image without having to create separate variables and tags.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use a visibility trigger instead it will return a gtm.element for each element that becomes visible (e.g. is in the viewport and not hidden via CSS) and you can read all it's properties. That would save you the dataLayer.push.

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff Thanks for your response. But we need to add some custom parameters so that the Tag can push those to GA. With a trigger we can't do that - unless we create a separate trigger for each image and this is not possible as the number of images are variable depending on conditions of user. Unless there is a way for the trigger to access data- attributes on an element. Is there?

Comment: You do not need separate triggers. The visibility event is triggered for every element that matches the selector (or for precision sake, there is a setting that allows you to have it triggered for every element).

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff But how do I access the custom data of an element from the trigger? For example if the element has an data-group attribute , how do I get that value?

Comment: This is just an ordinary Javascript Object, so something like "gtm,element.dataSet.group" (btw. I do not want to convince you to use a specific method - the advantage of the visibility trigger would be basically that you can do everything from within GTM and do not need extra logic in the page, but the dataLayer.push will work as well as long as each push has also an "event" key)

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff I would also like to use the Visibility trigger. Sorry to sound dumb! But how does gtm.element.dataSet.group get in there in the first place if using the Visibility trigger. I cannot see such properties no matter what I do?

Comment: I am still at work. I will give a more elaborate answer when I have a little time.

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff Thank you. Would greatly appreciate it.